# java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, object, combobox

I want to call course name in combobox and print  course Id which selected coursename How can I solve this problem?

```
    public void coursename(){
     Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
     Query query= session.createQuery("select a.courseName,a.courseId  from Semester e inner join e.course as a"); 
   for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
      Object  row[] = (Object[])   it.next();
      combocourse.addItem(row[0]);
        }        
       session.close();
   }


    private void combocourseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


  JComboBox combocourse = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();  
   Object row[] = (Object[])combocourse.getSelectedItem();  
    System.out.println("id"+row[1] ); 

       }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Exactly what error are you getting and on which line of your code?

Comment: String can not be cast to Array of Object...@ which line???

Comment: try to change `getSelectedItem` to `getSelectedObjects`, this returns you list of selected objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By not trying to cast a `String` to an `Object[]`. Look at the return value of the methods you're using, and use variables typed appropriately to store those return values.  [`JComboBox#getSelectedItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem--) returns an `Object` (in this case apparently a `String`), not an *array* (of any kind). But in this line:

```
Object row[] = (Object[])combocourse.getSelectedItem();
```

...you're trying to cast it to be an `Object[]` (array of `Object`) so you can store it in an `Object[]`. You can't do that.

It seems like `row` should just be `Object` or `String`, not `Object[]`, and that when you use it you should just use it directly, not as `row[1]`:

```
Object row = combocourse.getSelectedItem();  
System.out.println("id"+row );
```

Or

```
String row = (String)combocourse.getSelectedItem();  
System.out.println("id"+row );
```

---

In a comment you asked:

> I called coursename in combobox but i should save course id in my database. How can I get courseId?

I don't know `JComboBox`. Fundamentally, you need to store something that contains both values (the ID and name) and then use that something when you get the selected item. Unless `JComboBox` has some functionality for this built in, you might need a simple class for that that holds the values and implements `toString` by returning `courseName`. Something vaguely like:

```
class CourseItem {
    private String courseName;
    private String courseId; // Or int or whatever

    CourseItem(String courseName,String courseId) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return this.courseName;
    }

    public String getCourseId() {
        return this.courseId;
    }

    public String toString() { // For display
        return this.courseName;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public void coursename() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select a.courseName,a.courseId  from Semester e inner join e.course as a");
    for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
        Object row[] = (Object[]) it.next();
        combocourse.addItem(new CourseItem((String)row[0], (String)row[1]));
    }
    session.close();
}

private void combocourseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {


    JComboBox combocourse = (JComboBox) evt.getSource();
    CourseItem item = (CourseItem)combocourse.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("id" + item.getCourseId());

}
```

Comment: `Object  row[] = (Object[])it.next();` too... :)

Comment: @TAsk: Well, I don't know the query infrastructure being used there, so for all I know `it.next()` *does* return an array (perhaps an array of the values for the row being iterated). But yeah, just generally, the OP should look at what methods return and use an appropriately-typed variable to store those return values in.

Comment: Thanks i called coursename in combobox but i should save course id in my database.How can i get courseId?

Comment: @user3627624: I've added a bit to the answer about that.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Object row = (Object)combocourse.getSelectedItem();  
System.out.println("id"+row );
```

You only add single objects into the combocourse, not arrays of objects.

Answer (score 1):

`combocourse.getSelectedItem();` in your case returns `String` and string cannot be cast to array of objects. If you want to get List of Objects, they use  [`getSelectedObjects()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedObjects%28%29)